# rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException How do I avoid this error - its crashing my app

Tags: rx-java

com.myapp.test.debug E/MessageQueue-JNI: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException
                                                                                 at rx.Observable$31.onError(Observable.java:7134)
                                                                                 at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:154)
                                                                                 at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
                                                                                 at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:137)
                                                                                 at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:224)
                                                                                 at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:121)
                                                                                 at com.myapp.MyClass.lambda$static$53(MyClass.java:77)
where MyClass.java 77    MySubject.onNext(event);

A few question ...  Why is the actual error not also shown in addition to error handler not implemented?  Secondly where am I suppose to implement this function on my subject?  How exactly would I add an Error handler to the subject. Thanks this is crashing my app and the actual error is not even shown. I guess I should always implement the error handler?

Comment: which RxJava version are you using ? 
You can add an error handler on your stream by implementing the onError callback on your Observable. Example: `suject.subscribe(onNextCallback, onErrorCallback);`

Answer (score 4):

RxJava has an `Observable` and an `Observer`. You can view the `Observable` as the **source** of your stream on which you can perform operations such as `map` and `filter`. The `Observer` is kind of a **receiver**: it is an interface with three methods (`onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted`) that get triggered by the `Observable`. You connect an `Observable` and `Observer` via the `Observable.subscribe(...)` methods.

There are multiple overloads of `subscribe` that allow you to provide the `onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted` as separate functions. These functions are then used to implement the `Observer` interface. If you don't provide all three functions (say only `onNext`), the `onError` method of the `Observer` interface is implemented by throwing an `OnErrorNotImplementedException`.

Presumably your code looks something like this

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println); // I use a Java 8 lambda here for brevity
subject.onNext(1/0); // this causes an error for dividing by 0
```

You can '*catch*' this exception by not only providing an `onNext` implementation in the `subscribe`, but also providing an `onError` implementation:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStacktrace);
subject.onNext(1/0);
```

Regarding your last question "*Am I supposed to always implement the `onError` function?*": Technically speaking no, you don't need to if you are sure that the `Observable` (or `Subject`) will not produce an error. In practice however it is a smart idea to at least log this kind of error or even recover from it using an operator like `onErrorResumeNext` or `retry`. You can find all about them in the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of any subscriptions which could be causing errors. For instance I have a subscription doing an assert which returned true the first time but as the next value made the assertion throw an error then my observable was caught with this exception error.